# Сложный mysql select

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Есть 6 таблиц: [image]

- Manufacturer - производитель
- Drug - медикамент
- Unit - единица измерения + форма ("мл", "капли")
- Drug_unit - форма выпуска медикамента с объемом
- Drugstore - аптека
- Drugstore_drug_unit - продажа медикаментов в аптеках

Не могу придумать как сделать запрос:

**Вывести аптеки, в которых продается одно и то же лекарство различных производителей**

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Что значит **одно и то же лекарство различных производителей**? Судя по БД у Вас 1ому лекарству соответствует лишь один производитель

Comment: У вас реализована связь 1:М (1 товар может иметь только одного производителя). Реализуйте М:М, тогда все станет легче, или же перепишите вопрос, ибо сейчас в вопросе запрос не соответствует архитектуре БД.

Comment: Существует несколько производителей: пр1, пр2, пр3. Каждый из них может выпускать какой-то одинаковый медикамент, например, аспирин.  Задача в том, чтобы найти все аптеки, в которых продается аспирин более чем одного производителя. Без привязки к конкретному медикаменту. Получается: найти все медикаменты, которые производятся несколькими производ.; найти аптеки, в которых продаются эти медикаменты (в аптеке "абс" продается аспирин от пр1 и пр2); вывести эти аптеки.

Comment: @Вадим Вам выше уже ответили, что у Вас архитектура бд не позволяет это сделать. Так как 1 медикамент имеет 1 производителя, а не 1 медикамент имеет множество производителей

Comment: Для каждой аптеки получите список лекарств: например `['acпирин unit_form1', 'acпирин unit_form1', , 'ношпа unit_form2']` , и сравните длину этого списка с длиной это же списка но в котором остались только уникальные значения

Comment: У вас по хорошему не хватает еще пары таблиц. Вам надо как то связать одинаковые медикаменты разных производителей между собой. Если же вы просто свяжете один медикамент с несколькими производителями (как предлагают выше) то вы не поймете какой точно из них находится в аптеке